# How to deal with ill-conditioned neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, numerical-methods

When dealing with ill-conditioned neural networks, is the current state of the art to use an adaptive learning rate, some very sophisticated algorithm to deal with the problem, or to eliminate the ill conditioning by preprocessing/scaling of the data?

The problem can be illustrated with the simplest of scenarios: one input and one output where the function to be learned is y=x/1000, so a single weight whose value needs to be 0.001. One data point (0,0). It turns out to matter a great deal, if you are using gradient descent, whether the second data point is (1000,1) or (1,0.001).

- [Theoretical discussion of the problem, with expanded examples](ftp://ftp.sas.com/pub/neural/illcond/illcond.html).
- [Example in TensorFlow](https://github.com/russellw/tf-examples/blob/master/slowdown.py)

Of course, straight gradient descent is not the only available algorithm. Other possibilities [are discussed at here](ftp://ftp.sas.com/pub/neural/FAQ2.html#A_numanal) - however, as that article observes, the alternative algorithms it lists that are good at handling ill condition, are not so good when it comes time to handle a large number of weights.

[Are new algorithms available? Yes](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/train#Optimizers), but these aren't clearly advertised as solutions for this problem, are perhaps intended to solve a different set of problems; swapping in Adagrad in place of GradientDescent does prevent overshoot, but still converges very slowly.

At one time, there were some efforts to develop heuristics to adaptively tweak the learning rate, but then instead of being just a number, the learning rate hyperparameter is a function, much harder to get right.

So these days, is the state of the art to use a more sophisticated algorithm to deal with ill condition, or to just preprocess/scale the data to avoid the problem in the first place?

Comment: The poor behavior of steepest descent for ill-conditioned Hessians is well known in optimization theory ("zig-zagging"). Have you considered using a gradient-free search method?